# Can't put more than one command in a function?

Tags: ios, swift

I have had a problem with IOS swift. It is similar to objective-c. My problem is that whenever i run this specific piece of code in my view controller everything bugs out. I have 3 labels and one button. I want to click the button and have each label show a randomly generated number. I have tried multiple things such as putting the label variables in the function, also moving around the number.text line. The only time this code doesn't crash is when i only have on command in the function such as number.text = String(arc4random() % 6).

```
@IBOutlet weak var number: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var number1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var number2: UILabel!

@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

    number.text = String(arc4random() % 6)
    number1.text = String(arc4random() % 6)
    number2.text = String(arc4random() % 6)

}
```

Comment: What does "everything bugs out" mean exactly?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) That is the error that i get

Comment: Well, did you connect your IBOutlets in interface builder? Because they'll all be nil unless you did that. Which would probably cause you to unexpectedly find nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that number1 and number2 are actually connected to items in Interface Builder or created some other way.

It looks like they are nil and you're trying to edit their text property.

To test this, you can do something like this

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
   if (number != nil) {
        number.text = String(arc4random() % 6)
    }

    if (number1 != nil) {
        number1.text = String(arc4random() % 6)
    }

    if (number2 != nil) {
        number2.text = String(arc4random() % 6)
    }
}
```

Only the items that are actually created will be changed so you can see which are nil and which aren't

Updated for swift 3:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    number?.text = String(arc4random() % 6)
    number1?.text = String(arc4random() % 6)
    number2?.text = String(arc4random() % 6)
}
```

Comment: This was it. I didn't control click drag into my actual view controller, so it was nil.